# Get current serial counter when running Ansible play

Tags: ansible

I am running an Ansible play which uses the `serial` property to run against a subset of the hosts at a time.

I would like to get the current serial counter so I can use this to dynamically set a group name in an `add_host` task.

For example my hosts file is as follows:

```
"172.23.130.13",
"172.23.130.34",
"172.23.130.99",
"172.23.130.94"
```

My play is as follows:

```yaml
- name: Create Add and Remove Group Batches
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  become: true
  no_log: false
  serial: 2

  tasks:

    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.1 }}"
        ansible_ssh_port: 2020
        group: loadbalancer-{{ <<serial counter here>> }}
        action: add
      with_indexed_items: "{{ ansible_play_batch  }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

This play will run twice as `serial` is set to 2.  I would therefore like 2 groups to be created by the `add_host` task.  One group called `loadbalancer-1` and another called `loadbalancer-2`.

The group `loadbalancer-1` will contain the first 2 IPs from the hosts file and the group `loadbalancer-2` the next 2.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help people can offer.

Comment: Would the [loop control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html?highlight=loop%20control#loop-control) help? You could define the loop control variable and use that to group the hosts?

Comment: This question might be answered by the example of how to [controlling Ansible playbook execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035186/6771046).